# Catch OnDisconnected event on client side with SignalR Core

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

Is it possible to catch hub OnDisconnected event on javascript side with SignalR Core?

I need to do some actions on client side once OnDisconnected event is fired.

I tried to use onClose event by it didn't fire for instance in case I had updated the page or leave the page. But in this case OnDisconnected event on server side was fired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code for client connection and event handling.

sdk: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.7/signalr.min.js

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chathub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});

// Start the connection.
start();
```

Referred from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. onclose event doesn't fire when I am trying to refresh web page, but OnDisconnected event on server side works. So onclose doesn't fire in all cases

Comment: Checkout this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0

maybe you're using on older version.

Answer (score 0):

In your SignalR Hub server side code, add override functions for the OnConnected and OnDisconnected events.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
         string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

         _userConnections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
         await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);
         _logger.LogInformation("Connecting to SignalRHub for User: {0} with connection {1}", name, Context.ConnectionId);
          
         await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    } 

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex){
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    _logger.LogWarning("Disconnecting to SignalRHub for User: {0}", name);

    var msg = "some message";
    await Clients.Groups(name).SendAsync("jsListener", msg);
                           
    await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);           
}
```